# Use samAccount instead of UPN for Spring Security Active Directory Ldap Provider

Tags: java, spring, active-directory

I am working on a java application that uses [spring security's ldap provider](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) to authenticate users. Our AD (active directory) is configured so that the `UPN` (unique provider name) and `samAccount` are the same. However, the UPN will be changing, causing authentication to break. The issue could be resolved if I were able to change the ldap adapter to check `samAccount` instead of `UPN`. So far I have not been able to successfully authenticate a user by manually changing `userPrincipalName={0}` to `sAMAccountName={0}`. Their [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) seems to indicate that the adapter is specific to UPN. Can anyone confirm please?